# Why is the derived exception type lost when catching in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, inheritance

I'm currently playing around with exception types and I've noticed something odd when attempting to re-throw caught exceptions.
From the C++ specification, I know that `throw` actually produces a copy of the object you're attempting to throw, so you will end up slicing any residual derived-type information that you caught.
To avoid this, I have seen suggestions to re-`throw` a pointer to the original exception as the actual original object will then not have its derived portion removed.
However, the simple example program I've written below would seems to not work that way:

```cpp
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class derived_exception : public std::exception { };

void rethrowException(bool anonymise) {
  try {
    throw derived_exception();
  } catch(const std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << "Caught: " << typeid(e).name() << " (std::exception)" << std::endl;
    if(anonymise) {
      throw;
    } else {
      throw &e;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Re-throwing caught exception..." << std::endl;
  try {
    rethrowException(false);
  } catch(const derived_exception* e) {
    std::cout << "Re-caught: " << typeid(e).name() << " (derived_exception)" << std::endl;
  } catch(const std::exception* e) {
    std::cout << "Re-caught: " << typeid(e).name() << " (std::exception)" << std::endl;
  }
    std::cout << std::endl << "Re-throwing anonymous exception..." << std::endl;
  try {
    rethrowException(true);
  } catch(const derived_exception& e) {
    std::cout << "Re-caught: " << typeid(e).name() << " (derived_exception)" << std::endl;
  } catch(const std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << "Re-caught: " << typeid(e).name() << " (std::exception)" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

With the output of `./example`:

```
Re-throwing caught exception...
Caught: 17derived_exception (std::exception)
Re-caught: PKSt9exception (std::exception)

Re-throwing anonymous exception...
Caught: 17derived_exception (std::exception)
Re-caught: 17derived_exception (derived_exception)
```

You can successfully re-cast the pointer and retrieve the derived type information, but the pointer type is still initially sliced.
Is there any way around this without catching the base and attempting to `dynamic_cast` back?

Thanks

Comment: `derived_exception` is derived from `exception`, but `derived_exception*` is not derived from `exception*`.

Comment: As a corollary, don't catch exceptions by pointers - catch them by const references.

Comment: `anonymise` is a wrong name as when `true`, you got correct type, and with false, you got base type...

Comment: The throw/catch system won't `dynamic_cast` pointers for you.

Comment: "From the C++ specification, I know that throw actually produces a copy of the object you're attempting to throw, so you will end up slicing any residual derived-type information that you caught." - I don't think that's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. What `throw` throws?

> [C++14 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)
>
> **5.17 Throwing an exception**
>
> 3. A throw-expression with no operand rethrows the currently handled exception.
>
> **15.1 Throwing an exception**
>
> 3. **Throwing an exception copy-initializes a temporary object, called the exception object.** The temporary is an lvalue and is used to initialize the variable declared in the matching handler.

For statement `throw;`, it will re-throw the current exception object `derived_exception()`.

For statement `throw &e;`, it will create a temporary object of type `std::exception *`, effectively equivalent to `throw (std::exception *except_obj = &e);`.

### 2. Which `catch` catches?

> [C++14 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)
>
> **15.1 Throwing an exception**
>
> 3. Throwing an exception copy-initializes a temporary object, called the exception object. **The temporary is an lvalue and is used to initialize the variable declared in the matching handler.**
>
> **15.3 Handling an exception**
>
> 3. A handler is a match for an exception object of type E if
>
>    - [3.1] The handler is of type cv T or cv T& and E and T are the same type (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers), or
>    - [3.2] the handler is of type cv T or cv T& and T is an unambiguous public base class of E, or
>    - [3.3] the handler is of type cv T or const T& where T is a pointer type and E is a pointer type that can be converted to T by either or both of
>
>      - a standard pointer conversion (4.10) not involving conversions to pointers to private or protected or ambiguous classes
>      - a qualification conversion, or
>    - [3.4] the handler is of type cv T or const T& where T is a pointer or pointer to member type and E is std::nullptr_t.
> 4. The handlers for a try block are tried in order of appearance.

**When `anonymise == true`:**

`throw;` is executed, thus re-throw exception object `derived_exception()`, then to pick an entry point among:

- `catch(const derived_exception& e)`,
- and `catch(const std::exception& e)`.

From Standard 15.3-3-3.2, we know `derived_exception()` matches `catch(const derived_exception& e)`. Thus the output is:

```
Re-caught: 17derived_exception (std::exception)
```

**When `anonymise == false`:**

`throw &e;` is executed, thus create a temporary exception object of type `std::exception *`, then to pick an entry point among:

- `catch(const derived_exception* e)`,
- and `catch(const std::exception* e)`.

We can't pick the former one. Because none of the four rules in Standard 15.3-3 say `std::exception *` is considered a match of `const derived_exception *`.

So, the later `catch` is picked. We see output:

```
Re-caught: PKSt9exception (std::exception)
```

( You may want to argue about the third rule [3.3], but neither *standard pointer conversion* nor *qualification conversion* supports conversion from baseclass pointer to subclass pointer, down-casting must be done explicitly, like using`dynamic_cast<T>()`. )

### 3. In your question

> From the C++ specification, I know that throw actually produces a copy of the object you're attempting to throw,

Right.

> so you will end up slicing any residual derived-type information that you caught.

Right if you use value type instead of reference or pointer in `catch`. One example is

```
try {
    throw derived_exception();
} catch (const std::exception e) {
    ...
}
```

From Standard 15.1-3, we know here `e` will be initialized with `derived_exception()`. In effect, it's like executing `e = derived_exception();`. I can't find any reason to use this form, though.

> I have seen suggestions to re-throw a pointer to the original exception as the actual original object will then not have its derived portion removed.

By replacing `typeid(e).name()` with `typeid(*e).name()`, we can see the original object is not sliced:

```
catch (const std::exception *e)
{
    std::cout << "Re-caught: " << typeid(*e).name() << " (std::exception)"
              << std::endl;
}
// Re-caught: 17derived_exception (std::exception)
```